# numpy summing matrix-rows by indices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have 3 matrices (np arrays):
A is of shape (n,m) ; B is of shape (m,k); and C is of shape (n,k)

Matrix C has only values from the set {-1,0,1} and it's an "indicator" of some sort: if C[i,j]==1 then I want to add the i-th row of A to the j-th column of b; and if C[i,j]==(-1) then subtract (0 does nothing).

It can easily be done with loops, but I'm wondering if there's a vectorized way to do it that might be faster?

example code:

```
C = np.array([[-1,  0,  0,  0,  1],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
              [-1,  0,  0,  1,  1]])
a,b = np.where(C==1)
#here a=[0,3,3] and b=[4,3,4]
A[a,:] = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
          [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
B[:,b] += A[a]  #B is all 0.0 before
```

expected result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  8.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  9.]])
```

actual result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.]])
```

Comment: What is A before?

Comment: And, what is B before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply use `np.add.at` on the transposed view of `B` -

```
np.add.at(B.T, b, A[a])
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: C = np.array([[-1,  0,  0,  0,  1],
    ...:               [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
    ...:               [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
    ...:               [-1,  0,  0,  1,  1]])
    ...: a,b = np.where(C==1)
    ...: A = np.zeros((4,7),dtype=int)
    ...: A[a,:] = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    ...:           [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    ...:           [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [40]: # Initialize B
    ...: B = np.zeros((7,5),dtype=int)

In [41]: np.add.at(B.T, b, A[a])

In [42]: B
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 7],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 9]])
```

As [`commented by @DSM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157754/numpy-summing-matrix-rows-by-indices#comment87334095_50158107), we can also use matrix-mutiplication and hence avoiding the step to get indices for `C==1`  -

```
A.T.dot(C==1)
```

Comment: But if we also have to handle the C[i,j]==(-1)  case, isn't it just `A.T @ C`?

Comment: @DSM Well, we are not given the entire `A`, so I am just working with `A[a]` which is given. But yeah, I guess we could do that after setting all `-1s` to 0s.

Comment: A should have the same number of rows as C.

Comment: @Kefeng91 It has as the question states : `A is of shape (n,m) ; and C is of shape (n,k)`.

Comment: C is of shape (4, 5), your A is of shape (10, 7).

Answer (score 1):

I had a little trouble keeping this all straight in my head, but I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

n, m, k = 2, 3, 4 

# A is full of 1s
A = np.ones((n,m))
# B is full of 0s
B = np.zeros((m,k))
# C is...  that
C = np.array([
    [ 0,  0, -1,  1],
    [ 0, -1,  1,  0]
])

# Where to add A to B
add_x, add_y = np.where(C==1)
# Where to subtract A to B
sub_x, sub_y = np.where(C==-1)

# Select columns of B and += rows of A 
# (using .T to transpose A so it's the same shape)
B[:,add_y] += A[add_x,:].T
# ditto thing above, but for -=
B[:,sub_y] -= A[sub_x,:].T
print(B)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0. -1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  1.]]
```